# vectorizing assembly procedure of 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have following assembly procedure

```
nP = small integer ( 1~100 )
nQ = small but larger than nP
nE = large integer ( 10^5~7)

f  = @(x) math_expression % for example, sin(pi*x).^4

x    = (nQ x nE)
Mass = (nQ x nP)
```

What I want to construct is

```
M = (nP x nP x nE) : 3D matrix
```

by

```
h = x(nQ,:)-x(1,:);

for k = 1 : nE

     M(:,:,k) = Mass'*diag(f(x(:,k))*Mass*h(k);

end
```

This will be used to construct block diagonal matrix with predefined index matrices

```
sparse(IM(:),JM(:),M(:),nE*nP,nE*nP,nP*nP*nE);
```

What I want to do is removing `for` loop by vectorize

```
Mass'*diag(f(x(:,k))*Mass*h(k)
```

I tried to use `bsxfun` like

```
assmble = @(dummy,k) Mass'*diag(f(x(:,k))*Mass*h(k)
Mass = bsxfun(assmble,Mass,reshape(1:nE,1,1,nE));
```

However, matlab said it is not proper way to use `bsxfun`.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide a small-dimension example of inputs and correct outputs (_especially_ outputs). Also why are you using [_conjugate_ transpose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html)? I didn't think you had complex numbers in your problem.

Comment: One example is `nP=10` and `nQ=15`. Is there any difference between `'` and `.'` for real matrix `Mass`?

Comment: Obviously there's no difference, but if you get used to working like that, you'll forget that there's a difference when you need to use complex numbers and then it will be a major headache. It's better get rid of bad habits early on. For more information see [these docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/973/common-mistakes-and-errors/5141/the-transpose-operators#t=201608130818519503455).

Comment: Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a solution:

```
i = repmat(1:nQ,1,nE);
j = 1:(nQ*nE);
d = sparse(i,j,f(x(:)));
Mass_d = reshape(Mass'*d,nP,nQ,nE);
Mass_d_t = permute(Mass_d,[2,1,3]);
Mass_d_t_r = reshape(Mass_d_t, nQ ,nP*nE);
M_d_M = Mass'*Mass_d_t_r;
M_d_M_h = bsxfun(@times,M_d_M, repelem(h,nP));
M = reshape(M_d_M_h, nP , nP , nE);
```

However you may need clear unneeded variables to prevent memory problems